# Referencing a DIV Tag of one JSP from another JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, jsp

I am developing an application in spring. I have two files home.jsp and logs.jsp. When I click on one link present in home.jsp it shows logs.jsp in div tag of home.jsp but I have one button in logs.jsp when i press it, it should reflect the changes of logs.jsp in same div tag of home.jsp. But i am not able to get the reference of div tag of home.jsp inside logs.jsp. How can I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `<jsp:include>` to include jsp then you can refer.Otherwise you cannot refere from one jsp to another jsp

Comment: But this will load whole home.jsp inside home.jsp's div tag, Which i don't want I just want the div tag of home.jsp inside logs.jsp.Is there any way to do this otherwise what to do?

Comment: in my knowledge it is not possible